# ¿Cómo insertar con id que sea seguida?

Tags: php, sql

Para esta  bd

```
CREATE TABLE Clientes (
                ID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
                Nombres varchar(25) NOT NULL,
                Apellidos varchar(25)NOT NULL,
                DNI varchar(9) NOT NULL,
                numPersonas int,
                localidadOrigen varchar(25),
                tarjetaCredito varchar(16) NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (ID)
            )
```

Como puedo insertar el id que sea correlativo?, sin tener que hacer una consulta para saber cual es el último ID

Comment: No añadas la ID en la *INSERT*, esta se genera automáticamente incrementando en uno el valor de la ID anterior.

Comment: Si la tengo como clave primaria tambien me dejará?

Comment: El id se iniciará y continuará incrementándose en 1 por cada fila que registres en tu tabla, sin necesidad de que intervengas; por haber establecido que sea `AUTO_INCREMENT` y `PK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando estableces que una columna de tu tabla, tenga las siguientes características:

- `INT`
- `PRIMARY KEY`
- `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Le estas indicando a tu gestor lo siguiente:

- Inserta valores numéricos de tipo entero
- Establece el valor como `LLAVE PRIMARIA`, lo cual indica que no se debe repetir ningún registro, es decir las llas primarias son únicas
- El valor se auto incrementará a través del gestor por cada registro nuevo que insertes en la tabla; es decir por cada tabla, el valor de incremento por defecto es 1

**EJEMPLO**

Tabla

```
CREATE TABLE version (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   valor VARCHAR(2));
```

Inserción

```
INSERT INTO version(valor)
VALUES
("a"),
("b"),
("c"),
("d"),
("e"),
("f");
```

Muestra de la consulta a la tabla

```
SELECT * FROM version;
```

Resultados

```
ID  valor
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
```

Aunque tu puedes indicar desde que número deseas que empiece el incremento con una propiedad fuera del alcance de la declaración de las tablas, de este modo

```
CREATE TABLE version (
   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   valor VARCHAR(2)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10;
```

Dándome como resultado esto

```
ID  valor
10  a
11  b
12  c
13  d
14  e
15  f
```

- Aquí mas sobre [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)